# Save barcode Image generated with milon/barcode in my storage folder (in Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, barcode

I implemented this library to generate barcodes images in my laravel project
https://github.com/milon/barcode

Everything works fine, the image is generated correctly, but now i want save the barcode image in my storage folder

For the barcode image i just add a value in my database  and then i convert that value in a barcode image

This is the code where i add the value in my database:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('barcode', 'has-error') }}">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
        Barcode
    </label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {{ Form::text('barcode', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control required', 'minlength' => 3]) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code i use to generate the barcode image:

```
{!!  DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML("$employee->barcode", "C39")!!}
```

Comment: `"$employee->barcode"` shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: Just because php **can** execute the code, it doesn't mean it **should**. [Difference between single quotes and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/867418).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
\Storage::disk('public')->put('test.png',base64_decode(DNS2D::getBarcodePNG("4", "PDF417")));
```

Make sure your storage folder has write permission.

Comment: do i put this in my controller or when i generate the barcode image ??

Comment: Generate image in controller, save it and then pass it to view, you are generating it inside view that is not a good practice.

Comment: ok thanks that helped me a lot ,but how can i put the value of the barcode as the name of the image that i store 
and how can i save the image as a blob

Comment: Thanks Faraz! The key here is base64_decode.  I had a scenario where I just wanted to literally pass an image back to the requestor.  I actually passed this directly back in a response method because I didn't have a need to store to disk. return response(base64_decode(DNS1DFacade::getBarcodePNG($content,'C39')),200,['Content-Type' => 'image/png']);